# How would i write an abstract method?

Tags: java

Is there any possible way that I could write a `abstract method` that would take in an `int` value but `return` a `double`?

Comment: this is a joke, right?  is there some way to filter questions by rep?

Comment: Sorry i am new to Java.

Comment: if you are sincere then I do apologize.

Comment: There is exactly one possible way to do that. Not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

In an abstract class, define it like this:

```
public abstract double method(int param);
```

In the concrete class that extends from the abstract class and implements the method, do this:

```
public double method(int param) {
    return 0.0; // return what you need
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the best answer, by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is quite simple:

```
public abstract double mymethod(int n);
```

Remember that `abstract` methods by definition have no body. I suggest you read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) on abstract methods and classes.

Answer (score 0):

**SuperType**

```
public abstract class MyClass{

  abstract double convert(int x);
}
```

**SubType**

```
public class MyClassImpl extends MyClass {

    @Override
    double convert(int x) {
        return x;
    }

}
```

Comment: The cast is unnecessary, as indeed is the entire method.